# Spring boot mvn clean package .jar throws different exceptions than on local intellij run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am building a spring boot application and running into the following problem. When I run my application in my IDE IntelliJ everything works fine. If I then run mvn clean package, I am recieving the resulting .jar file in the /target folder. But when I run this .jar on my windows server I get lazyInit exceptions all over the place, which did not occur on my local machine.

Does anyone has a idea what could be the problem here?

Both machines local and server are running on java 11 and mysql 8.

Here's my poml.xml, but feel free to ask for other information I am not sure what could be needed here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.schuessler-plan.</groupId>
    <artifactId>acquisition.backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>acquisition.backend</name>
    <description>Backend for SP acquisition</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
            <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.tongfei</groupId>
            <artifactId>progressbar</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>customJAR</groupId>
            <artifactId>SimbaJDBCClient42</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>de.schuesslerplan.acquisition.backend.Application</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xms256m
                        -Xmx1g
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>in-project</id>
            <name>In Project Repo</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}\libs\</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

EDIT: One example of a lazyInit Exception.

`"failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: backend.model.mysql.Employee.registeredWork, could not initialize proxy - no Session"`

EDIT: Configuration differences in the application.yml for different profiles.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-request-size: 10MB
      max-file-size: 10MB

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
  jpa:
    show-sql: 'true'
mysql:
  driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name
  password: pass-local
  username: username-local
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
server:
  port: 8080

---

spring:
  profiles: prod
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
mysql:
  driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name
  password: pass-server
  username: username-server
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store-password: keystorepass
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    enabled: 'true'
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
```

Comment: Why is there a maven-assmbly-plugin in your setup? Why `<url>file://${project.basedir}\libs\</url>`??

Comment: Remove the `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Comment: Are both machines local and server running on SAME mysql 8?

Comment: @khmarbaise I just edited the poml.xml. I used the maven-assembly-plugin to integrate a external jar file I need. (last dependency added)

Comment: @WladimirDiskowski yes both machines are running on same mysql 8

Comment: @M.Deinum can not remove it because I use this to integrate a external jar file

Comment: That jar should be a dependency, Spring BOot will create the fat jar, doing this again with the assembly plugin will create an improper jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed the maven-assembly-plugin but I am still getting the same lazy init errors, which I do not get in my local machine. Also updated my initial post

Comment: Most important step is to show those exceptions/failures in the post...without them it's more or less impossible to even guess what the problem might cause...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your comment. I added one example of the lazy init failures and I know how to handle them, but my question is why I do not have the same exceptions on my local machine.

Comment: Then there must be something different configuration wise. Do you provide other properties between the 2 versions?

Comment: @M.Deinum I just added my application.yml file. There are the only differences configuration wise between the two builds

Comment: Well there is a big difference your dev doesn't contain `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` whereas your prod does. Which is "just a property" but has quite big implications. Either make sure those match between dev and prod or add it to dev as well and fix the issues you get with that.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks a lot! I should've seen that earlier!